# Can Whisper AI downgrade its large model from version 3 to version 2?

Tags: whisper

Whisper AI released an upgrade, [from v2 to v3](https://huggingface.co/openai/whisper-large-v3), of its large model in November. Before I upgrade, I would like to be certain that I can downgrade in case I need to. How do I do that? Can't see anything about it in the linked article.

Comment: You do you think you may need to downgrade?

Comment: @ChanganAuto If the results are worse (I am mostly not using English), if it requires more memory than my machine has etc. Whisper has become a crucial tool in my workflow.